# Issue passing a List<int> in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have the following method that calculates the top 20 numbers in a list and returns them.

```
static public List<int> CalculateTop20(List<int> nums)
{
    List<int> Returned = new List<int>();

    int count = nums.Count;

    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        var most = (from i in nums
                    group i by i into grp
                    orderby grp.Count() descending
                    select grp.Key).First();

        Returned.Add(most);
        nums.RemoveAll(item => item == most);
    }
    return Returned;
}
```

Except when I return them to main and try to output them to console they just come up as : System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Int32]...

I have multiple other methods passing lists throughout the program but this is the only one that is giving me this issue. Also when I output them right there while they're calculated the numbers are correct.

Comment: `List<T>` does not override its `ToString` method, so of course it's not gonna get written in a pretty way. Could you post the writing code?

Comment: How are you printing the List in the console?

Comment: That is precisely the type of the list - Are you just doing a .ToString() for your console printing?

Comment: Just a simple for loop to test it.  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Top20);
            }

Comment: Then you should try `for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { Console.WriteLine(Top20[i]); }` *(see the missing `[i]` at the end?)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're just calling `Console.WriteLine()` on the result that's all you'll get, it just calls `ToString()` on the object which prints the type name.

If you want to output the list you'll need to do something like this:

```
foreach(var i in list) {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: linqy way: `list.foreach(item => Console.WriteLine(item));`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the top 20 items from a List why not use LINQ?

```
// A sample list with 100 integers
var list = new List<int>();
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    list.Add(i);
}

// Get the top 20
var top20 = list.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(20);
```

**Edit:**

```
// Get the top 20 distinct values
var top20 = list.Distinct().OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(20);
```

Comment: Because I am looking for the top 20 unique numbers in a list. Doesn't this just take the top 20 numbers in the list regaurdless of it's fequency?

Comment: Toss a `.Distinct()` in there and you're set. Much better than re-sorting the list 20 times!

Comment: var top20 = list.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(20).Distinct(); - Would that be the proper syntax?

Comment: No, list.Distinct().OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(20). If you call distinct AFTER taking 20 you may end up with less than 20 items if there were duplicates.

Comment: Oh ok, that is going to take the distinct out of the 20 that are chosen. Thank You!